# What is the name of the data object being passed from a jQuery ajax call to a Ruby controller?

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is the .ajax call. The variable `questions` is a JSON object:

Object `{question_1: "3", question_2: "6", question_3: "9", question_4: "15", question_5: "12"}`

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/save",
      data: questions,
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function (data) {
        alert('success');
      }
      });
```

My ruby contorller.

```
def save
 # How do I access the data object?
end
```

Do I just do a params[:data] or params[:questions] ?

Thanks and while I found other questions similar to this, none mentioned what the actual parameter name is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's whatever you've made the questions variable. If you've included a root object

```
{"question": { ... }}
```

It'll be accessible at `params[:question]`

Otherwise the attributes will be included in the root of the `params` hash along with anything Rails adds and the URL attributes.

By the by, I would expect the data in a variable called `questions` to look something like this:

```
{ "questions": [{ ... }, { ... }]}
```

Comment: Would I then need to have Ruby parse it into a hash or is that done automatically? something like: @data = JSON.parse(params[:questions])

Comment: No, if you set your controller to `respond_to :json` then it will parse it automatically.

Comment: so at the top of my controller i'll need to add: respond_to do |format|
  format.json { #put all controller logic here? }
end

Comment: No. You need to read up on Controllers: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html Why not have the save action simply `render :text => params.inspect` so you can see what is getting sent in?

Comment: because there are no parameters being posted to it at that point

Comment: My advice is to read up on Controllers before trying to do things like this. You just said you're posting that `questions` object. To see how it appears just look at the params coming in with the request in the terminal. Going from what you said it should be `params[:question_1]` etc

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20660/discussion-between-jack-marchetti-and-jonny-h)